# How to create local p2 repository which supports multiple target paltform

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho, p2

I have created a eclipse plugin and its feature and update site... everything is under a master project.
The strucute is

```
Test master
--test-plugin
--test-feature
--test-update site
```

I converted all the projects into maven with the help of Tycho and also i have some dependency problem so am in need of p2 repository so i created a local p2 repository as mentioned by Nick wilson [Project dependency error when using my local p2 repository with necessary jar files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647422/project-dependency-error-when-using-my-local-p2-repository-with-necessary-jar-fi) here... but it supports only my platform windows 32 bit. It shows error in maven build at the master pom file for the environments here...

```
<environment>
          <os>linux</os>
          <ws>gtk</ws>
          <arch>x86</arch>
        </environment>
        <environment>
          <os>linux</os>
          <ws>gtk</ws>
          <arch>x86_64</arch>
        </environment>
```

So, I came to know that we have to create a p2 repository which supports all the platform. How can i create it? Because after testing my plugin in my local system ,I have to put it in CI server(jenkins) it is in linux . There the build fails so i am very much in need of this.I googled many sites,everyone says something with the product file. but i dint create any product definition file . iguess i wont require product definition file because without it , the project will generate a eclipse plugin during maven build.Am new for eclipse plugin tycho and in confusion too .please help me....

Comment: By using the p2 repository you created yourself (see linked question) you'll have problems that nobody else will have.

Comment: Given that one has to read the lenghy, linked question to be able to guess the cause for the troubles you are having, this is not a good question.

Comment: @oberlies :Thanks for your response. But I have created a p2 repository which contains only one version of swt. I need to know how to create a p2 repository which will contains all the swt versions supports all the target platform.

Comment: If you can provide a concise, yet complete description of how you created the p2 repository for one platform (and its not the questionable approach from the linked question), we may be able (and willing) to help.

Comment: i created the p2 repository as mentioned in the link. but it supports only my platform(windows 32 bit).I have created the repository by using the following command in working eclipse directory /myfolder/eclipse.exe -consolelog -nosplash -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher -metadataRepository file:/myfolder/p2-repo/ -artifactRepository file:/myfolder/p2-repo/ -source /myfolder/eclipse -publishArtifacts and it sucessfully created the repository.

Comment: but the error is the p2 doesn't support the Linux environment and shows error in my pom.  [ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not determine SWT implementation fragment bundle for environment {osgi.ws=gtk, osgi.os=linux, osgi.arch=x86, org.eclipse.update.install.features=true} -> [Help 1] org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not determine SWT implementation fragment bundle for environment {osgi.ws=gtk, osgi.os=linux, osgi.arch=x86, org.eclipse.update.install.features=true}

Comment: Publishing the artifacts yourself is very questionable, and could cause all kinds of problems. And and least I'm not going to help you with your self-made problems.